# Seleccionar un dato (double) en específico en JSON para ponerlos en un ListBox

Tags: c#, json, windows-forms

lo que pasa es que quiero seleccionar una lista de decimales (doubles) de un archivo JSON y mostrar lo que contiene la lista en un ListBox, esto es más o menos lo que hice:

```
string json = @"{
        "Personas":
        [
            {
                "Nombre":"Juan",
                "Promedios":[6.0, 5.1, 5.1, 5.2]
            },
            {
                "Nombre":"Pedro",
                "Promedios":[6.0, 5.1, 5.1, 5.2]
            }
        ]
}";

JObject objeto = JObject.Parse(json);
string match = objeto["Personas"]
     .Where(jt => (string)jt["Nombre"] == "Juan")
     .Select(jt => (string)jt["Promedios"])
     .FirstOrDefault();
    
if (match != null)
{
       listBox1.Items.Add(match);
}
```

Bueno, el punto es que no me aparecen los promedios de Juan en el ListBox, intenté con foreach pero me da errores, gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si simplemente queres cargar el `array` de double en un `listbox` podes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:
1- Crear las clases de tu json

2- Usar la libreria `Newtonsoft.Json` para deserealizar el json a tu objeto y le pasas el array al `datasource`

3- Si usas el Listbox.Items.Add estas agregando un elemento. Mejor le pasas la solucion que te doy para agregar un rango de elementos.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

string json = @"{
    "Personas":
    [
        {
            "Nombre":"Juan",
            "Promedios":[6.0, 5.1, 5.1, 5.2]
        },
        {
            "Nombre":"Pedro",
            "Promedios":[6.0, 5.1, 5.1, 5.2]
        }
    ]
 }";

var jsonresult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ListadoPersona>(json);

 List<float> promedios = new List<float>();

 foreach (var item in jsonresult.Personas)
 {
      if (item.Nombre == nombre) //nombre es la variable que pasas para elegir un estudiante
      {
           promedios = item.Promedios.ToList();
      }
 }

comboBox1.DataSource = promedios;

public class ListadoPersona
{
    public Persona[] Personas { get; set; }
}

public class Persona
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public float[] Promedios { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Pero... cómo añado todo eso al ListBox? ya que quiero que las decimales "Promedios" estén ahí dentro

Comment: el promedio de que persona?

Comment: los promedios de Juan

Comment: @Rhammy si te sirvio marcala como aceptada.